# How to give my view the same background color as the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to give my view the same background color as the (light gray) navigation bar. In Xcode (IB), I'm attempting to set the view's background color using the "Developer" palette in the color picker.

The problem is that when I select one of the two colors that I think are what I'm looking for here ("controlColor" and "windowBackgroundColor"), Xcode instead makes them solid red (all of the other color choices in the developer palette render properly, except for these two which are made red).

Is this Xcode's way of telling me I'm not allowed to do this? How else can I get my view's background color to match the color of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the view you want to change the color. select background color and then other. Go to the very left the color pallet
. slightly lower the arrow on the right and stop at the level that you see would match the color of the nag bar. that should give you the exact color of the default nag bar.
note: i just created a sample master detail project and did the same in the view of the detail view and it gives you the exact match of the color. hope that this helps you out.

here is the screen shot of the detail view with the changed color:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding this bit: "Go to the very left the color pallet . slightly lower the arrow on the right". I'm not sure which part of the color picker you're referring to.

Comment: when you select other from the drop down menu while you are trying to select a different color for your view, it will present you with a new window. in that window you have 4 options on the top. the color pallet looks like an orb or circle. it is the one on the very left side of that window on the top.